# Android OrientationEventListener making to many calls

Tags: java, android, sdk, orientation, android-sensors

I have a video on my app and I'm trying to achieve that when the user rotates his device from portrait to landscape the video changes to full-screen.

I'm using `OrientationEventListener` like this:

```
orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            if (orientation <= 45 && playerManager.isFullscreen()) {
                onPlayerFullscreenChange(false); //ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            } else if (orientation <= 135 && !playerManager.isFullscreen()) {
                onPlayerFullscreenChange(true); //ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            } else if (orientation <= 225 && playerManager.isFullscreen()) {
                onPlayerFullscreenChange(false); //ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            } else if (orientation <= 315 && !playerManager.isFullscreen()) {
                onPlayerFullscreenChange(true); //ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            }
        }
    };
```

The problem is that this listener gets called so many times that my video can't play normally. The activity ends up going throw the `OnCreate` multiple times unlike before.

Answer (score 0):

The onOrientationChanged(int orientation) method notifies you everytime the sensor detects a change in the way you are holding the Android device.

It is nearly impossible for a user to hold the device still, thus the onOrientationChanged() gets called multiple times.

What I have understood from your question is that, you only want to display a video in fullscreen when the user holds the device horizontally.

Thus consider angular values of 0-45, 135-255, and 315-360 as VERTICAL.
And, angles between 45-135 and 225-315 as HORIZONTAL.
This will make sense if you give it some thought.

Store the "previous orientation", which you can set to null initially for example, if you use String. Then compare it with the currently detected orientation, if they are not the same, take an action (set video to full screen or vice-versa) and save the current orientation values as "previous orientation".

This problem really comes down to better implementing your algorithm. All the best!